# Access Dropbox files when iPad is offline

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'd like my native iOS app to be able to access all my dropbox files on my iPad when the iPad is offline.  I have played with Dropbox's Roulette app but it seems to stop working as soon as you go offline.

Is it possible to build an app that integrates with Dropbox and which will access the offline Dropbox storage when the iPad is offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's not possibile since Dropbox is an online service and storage.

Consequences are that you can use it, the app retrieves the content from remote, and as soon as you disconnect, that won't work anymore.

For what you are saying, there should be some caching methods, in order to retrieve the contents and save them offline.

But think about it: if someone has big files on Dropbox, 200-500+ mb, that would be hard retrieving and caching the content, the iPad's storage would be filled in less than a few minutes!

So, except Dropbox doesn't put a function like this, i think that all you can do is to continue using Dropbox like you've always do.

Comment: Actually, you can "favourite" any files from within the dropbox app which will then be available offline. There might be a way to access these files by scouring the iPad file system, but you'll have to find out where the dropbox app stores them (maybe the /documents path).

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot about that! But yes, should definitely be the Documents path.